# cron job : cpanel to backup mysql daily dosn't work

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron, cpanel

I'm trying to take backup every day and want to name the file by date, but it doesn't work:

```
mysqldump DATABASE -u USER -pPASSWORD > "/home/backups/$(date +%d-%m-%Y)_db_backup.sql"
```

Comment: if you are run this file manually then it work or not?

Comment: I can't because this is shared hosting (Godaddy) cant run command

Comment: I think you should make a php file where you need to put backup code then set it in cron job

Comment: you're not able to set file name correctly OR you're unable to set schedule backup from godaddy cpanle?? what is your problem ?

Comment: I made php file to take backup and remove old files , thanks @Irfan